# White screen comes from debugging on another device in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

The app runs and works fine on the android emulator and when I run it on my phone. But I wanted to share the app so i created a release apk using flutter build apk --split-per-abi but after installing the app on their mobiles the first screen loads and immediately a blank white screen appears and nothing happens. Such error doesn't arise when i run the app in android studio

Comment: if your app runs on the internet, then you need to set Internet permission in manifest.xml.

Comment: @laxminarayan1998 i set all the permissions